# C++11 Threads vs. OpenMP when using a single thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, openmp

I am trying to parallelize code that is run many times (and hence, milliseconds count). I would like to use C++11 threading, as it can run natively on Mac OS X, as opposed to requiring the user to install OpenMP (e.g. using Homebrew). However, I find that OpenMP's performance is substantially better than C++11 threading.

Surprisingly, even when C++11 is only using a single thread, it has substantially more overhead than OpenMP. For the simple loop below we have the following times (using only one thread):

```
C++11 Multithreading: 57 ms
OpenMP Multithreading: 47 ms
Native for loop: 43 ms
```

I see more dramatic improvements in speed for OpenMP over C++11 threads when using more than 1 thread. How can I get OpenMP-type speeds with C++11 threading?

Here is some adapted code that more or less does what my actual code is trying to do.

**C++11 Multithreading**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

long int diff(timespec start, timespec end)
{
    long int tv_nsec;
    tv_nsec = 1000000000*(end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    return tv_nsec;
}
int main() {

    int n = 1E6;
    int ndim = 3;
    int nthreads = 1;
    double * arr1 =(double*) malloc(n* sizeof(double));
    double * arr2 =(double*) malloc(n* sizeof(double));
    double * xs=(double*) malloc(n* sizeof(double));
    double * ys =(double*) malloc(n* sizeof(double));
    int * iarr =(int*) malloc(n* sizeof(int));
    double * arr3 =(double*) malloc(n*ndim *sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i++ ; i<n) {
        iarr[i] = i;
        xs[i] = i;
        ys[i] = i; for (int j = 0; j++ ; j<ndim) {
            charges[j*ndim +i] = i*j;
        }
    }

        struct timespec start10,start20, end10, end20;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start10);

        {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads(nthreads);
        for (int t = 0; t < nthreads; t++) {
            threads[t] = std::thread(std::bind(
                    [&](const int bi, const int ei, const int t)
                    {
                        for(int i = bi;i<ei;i++)
                        {
                            {
                                arr1[i] = xs[iarr[i]];
                                arr2[i] = ys[iarr[i]];
                                for (int idim=0; idim<ndim; idim++){
                                        arr3[idim*n+i] = charges[idim*n +iarr[i]];
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    },t*n/nthreads,(t+1)==nthreads?n:(t+1)*n/nthreads,t));
        }
        std::for_each(threads.begin(),threads.end(),[](std::thread& x){x.join();});
        }


        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end10);
        printf("Initializing and sorting (%d threads): %.2lf ms\n",nthreads, (diff(start10,end10))/(double)1E6);
```

**OpenMP:**

```
        struct timespec start10,start20, end10, end20;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start10);

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(1)
    {
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){

                                arr1[i] = xs[iarr[i]];
                                arr2[i] = ys[iarr[i]];
                                for (int idim=0; idim<ndim; idim++){
                                        arr3[idim*n+i] = charges[idim*n +iarr[i]];
                                }

                            }
    }
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end10);
        printf("Initializing and sorting (%d threads): %.2lf ms\n",nthreads, (diff(start10,end10))/(double)1E6);
}
```

Comment: In C++ code you actualy uses **n+1** threads: take into account the main thread too. As far as I understand, OpenMP utilize the main thread among "n" threads.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, wow I think you are right. Do you know if there's any way to also use the main thread among the "n" threads in C++11?

Comment: "if there's any way to also use the main thread?" - Just call given function in the main thread.

Comment: I'm sorry - but if OpenMP is slower than your "Native" (serial?) loop, why would you even want to get OpenMP speed. Please provide a better description of your bigger workflow and an appropriate [mcve]. For this scale of runtime, you must preserve the threads to get efficient performance. OpenMP implementations can use thread pools, but there is no guarantee.

Comment: Please state your compiler options, your compiler, your OS, and your hardware. The optimization level you used is the most interesting.

Comment: Don't include the thread launch and thread join time in your timing information. I believe OpenMP uses a thread pool.